# Backbone JS Models: Hiding a dropdown

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Please excuse me if this is a silly question. I'm trying to hide a dropdown based on the attributes value in the Backbone models something like this

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize: function(options) {
   // I have access to this.attributes here
   if(options.name == 'Test') {
    // hide the subject dropdown

   }
}
});
```

I'm trying to hide the dropdown but looking for ideas to figure out what is the right approach to do this? Since the dropdown is in a Backbone form I'm wondering if I can just set the type to 'Hidden' in the models

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** do this in a model. Model is for storing data, hiding a dropdown is presentation logic. It should be done inside the view.

So basically your view will have something like

```
if(this.model.get('name') === 'pink'){
  this.$('#pinks-dropdown').hide();
}
```

What you can have in the model is a method that does some operations on it's data, so you can have a method like this in mode:

```
isNameMatchingSomething: function(){
  // some big logic
  return this.get("name") === 'pink';
}
```

And you can use this for hiding dropdown in view like:

```
if(this.model.isNameMatchingSomething()){
  this.$('#pinks-dropdown').hide();
}
```